# Find mode for probability distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have

$f(x) = 0, x < 6$

$f(x) = log_{16}(x-5), 6 <= x <= 21$

$f(x) = 1, x > 21$

How to find mode of this function? Should I make it equal to zero and then solve? or find derivative first and then?

Comment: $f$ is not a PDF. I suspect it is meant to denote a CDF (usually denoted with capital $F$). You should find the corresponding PDF by taking its derivative and then find maxima of this PDF.

Comment: @drhab So basically I have to find second derivative, make it equal to 0 and then solve, right?

Comment: Yes, it boils down to finding where its second derivatibe takes value $0$. I commented that you had to find maxima of the derivative but actually you must find *where* it takes maximal value.

Comment: @drhab I don't think that function (second derivative) takes 0 somewhere

Comment: I haven't checked, but the essence is that you must localize a maximum of the PDF. It can even have a maximum if it has no derivative.

Comment: Take one derivative to find the density.  Then sketch the density to spot the  mode, or take the second derivative and spot it is always negative